# Webmail random gaps nightmare!

Tags: html, email, webmail

I am trying to put together a html email for a client.  I'm used to XHTMl/CSS so its proving to be a complete pain as I believe old school tables are the correct way to go.  I have chopped up my image using Photoshop slicing tool.  Exported and added links using dreamweaver.  All works fine in browser and in Outllok, but webmail has random gaps between rows.  The code seems fine, so it doesn't make any sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally sussed the issue - all images need to have display:block and border:0 to clear the gaps!!

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS styles are clashing with the webmail's CSS styles. It is an ugly hack, but for HTML e-mails, using inline styles allows you to override most of the styling, and have a semi-decent looking message. For example, like this:

```
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
```

(of course, I always add a link at the top "not looking right? click here to view", linking to a webpage with the same content as your message)